# ssrs 2008 - remove row where column group total = 0

Tags: ssrs-2008

in ssrs 2008, I am getting My report output like below

[image]
I need to remove/hide sr.no. = 3, condition to apply where total qty=0

I used RowVisibility Show or Hide but output shows : Sr.No. is showing like 1 , 2 , 4  **(my serial number should come  in line 1,2,3 and hide the row where total = 0)**

thru tablix property applied filter as below but it is not filtering output 
   (
      I tried 
      [expression] = Sum(Fields!QTY.Value, "DataSet1")
      Text
      [Operator] = <>
      [Value] = 0 or ""

I have row groups like [matrix_descriptopn,  Matrix_OutletGroup , Outlet]
I have Colum Groups like  [Matrix_month]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you filter out rows having total = 0 from your dataset query ?

Comment: I tried, may be I am missing something, you can see above i tried , can you please give me a step to do

Comment: But could you show me your SQL query for your dataset?

Comment: You can try to remove "dataset1" from your filter and change Text to Integer or Float. Something like: [expression] = Sum(Fields!QTY.Value) Integer [Operator] = <> [Value] 0

Comment: Hi, I tried, as you said, but it is not showing any data, visible header and total only, I need to hide = 0 value, I tried = operator than also same thing

Answer (score 1):

I would recode the filter e.g.

```
[expression] = Sum(Fields!QTY.Value) <> 0 
Boolean 
[Operator] = 
[Value] True
```

This is the only reliable way I have found to use Filters in SSRS.

Comment: Hi, I applied filter as you told under rowgroup [outlet], I am getting message, An error occurred during local report processing, The processing for the grouping 'OUTLET' cannot be performed. cannot compare data od types system, string and system.boolean, Please check data type returned by the filterexpression

Comment: You probably missed equal sign. However you can not use aggregate functions in data set filter. Try this (and don't miss equal sign in expression):
[expression]    =Fields!QTY.Value <> 0 
Boolean 
[Operator]      = 
[Value]         True

Comment: hi, now I am not getting error, but when report generated it is showing header & total only, actually it should hide total = 0 row only

Comment: added two more images in main question, please check, if I do value=true or value= false , getting header & total only in reports

Comment: You need to clarify your comment - exactly what rows/groups do you mean by "header & total"?

Comment: hi mike, I mean header andtotal mening, when I apply filter than report output shows header & totals only, when I remover filter it shows data also.